# How to solve for r?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have

$ {}^{18}C_{2r+4}={}^{18}C_{r-2}$.

By hit and trial i see $r=6$ satisfies. But is there easy way to get that explicitely?

Thanks

Comment: Try: $2r+4 = 18-(r-2)$.

Comment: Thanks for stopping by.i got it

Comment: And also $2r+4=r-2$, naturally.